# Does $^nC_{n+1}$ exist?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinations

is there any value assigned to $^nC_{n+1}$?

My teacher wrote it equal to $0$, but what will negative factorial mean?

$$^nC_{n+1} = \frac{n!}{(n+1)!\cdot(n-n-1)!} = \frac{n!}{(n+1)!\cdot(-1)!}$$

Thanks

Comment: In several uses it is *defined* $\;\binom nk=0\;$ for $\;k>n\;$ .

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/709528/589.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula
$$C(m,n)=\frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}$$
is valid only if $m\ge n\ge 0$.

$C(m,m+1)$ is the number of subsets of $m+1$ elements in a set of $m$. Since there are no such subsets, $C(m,m+1)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

A formula for ${}^{n}C_k$ valid for any complex number $n$ is
$$ {}^n C_k = \frac{n(n-1)\dotsm(n-k+1)}{k!}. $$
If $n$ is an integer, and $k$ is an integer larger than $n$, the numerator contains the term $(n-(n+1-1)=0$, so the whole thing is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented on in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1113225/18880), a much more useful general definition of binomials coefficients is
$$
  \binom nk =  \frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{k!},
  \qquad\text{for aribtrary $n$, and for $k\in\Bbb N$,}
$$
possibly complemented by the convention the $\binom nk=0$ whenever $k$ is a negative integer (but such cases are much less often needed). This formula has no problem with having $k>n$, in which case it will give $0$ if (and only if) $n\in\Bbb N$, due to a factor $(n-n)=0$ in the numerator. This formula has the additional advantage of giving meaningful values when $n$ is negative or a fraction, or even a formal indeterminate. Many of the identities remain valid (but *not* the symmetry $\binom nk=\binom n{n-k}$), and one has [Newtons generalised binomial formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series). See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/351722/18880) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/597842/18880).